# How to resolve could not initialize class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader?

Tags: spring, struts2

I want to integrate struts2 with spring. so i am using the follwing code in my web-inf/classes folder.

applicationcontext.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
    <beans>
     <bean id="helloWorldClass" class="com.test.spring.HelloWorld" >
          <property name="message" value="Hello World!" />
     </bean>
     </beans>
```

struts.xml

```
    <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC 
         "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration  2.0//EN"
         "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
    <struts>    
    <struts-config>
    <!-- Spring Struts plugin -->
<plug-in className="org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn">
    <set-property property="contextConfigLocation"
        value="/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml" />
</plug-in>
    </struts-config>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="helloWorld" class="helloWorldClass">
        <result name="SUCCESS">/success.jsp</result>
    </action>
    </package>
    </struts>
```

I have used these file and one class which is helloWorld with the package as com.test.spring. Only getter/setter method of variable message is included in class.

content in pom.xml file:

```
            <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://snapshots.jboss.org/maven2</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>opensymphony-releases</id>
        <name>Opensymphony Releases</name>
<url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/opensymphony-releases</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>mvn-adamgent</id>
        <url>http://mvn-adamgent.googlecode.com/svn/maven/release</url>
        <name>Adam Gent Maven Repository</name>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>

     <repository>
    <id>springsource-milestones</id>
    <name>SpringSource Milestones Proxy</name>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/springsource-milestones</url>
     </repository>      
</repositories> 
     <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
           <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>    
        <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>   
        <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
 <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
<version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>   
    <dependency>
<groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
<artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
<version>2.3.13</version>
   </dependency>            
   <dependency>
<groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
<artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
<version>2.6.11</version>
   </dependency>            
    <dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
<artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1.6</version>
   </dependency>           
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
<artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
<version>2.1.6</version>
  </dependency>            
<dependency>
<groupId>com.opensymphony</groupId>
<artifactId>xwork</artifactId>
<version>2.1.2</version>
   </dependency>            
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
<artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1.6</version>
 </dependency>            
<dependency>
<groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
<artifactId>antlr-runtime</artifactId>
<version>3.1.3</version>
  </dependency>          
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
<version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>                
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
<version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>            
<!-- Spring framework --> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency> 
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-struts</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
         <version>2.5.6</version>
       </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>testspring</finalName>
       </build>
    </project>
```

By using this file i have downloaded jar files in web-inf/lib folder in target.

When i upload this war file on glassfish server it showing following error message.

**Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader. Please see server.log for more details.**

Can anyone please help me to solve this error and how to integrate struts2 with spring.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why are you using both Spring 3 and Spring 2 in your app? IMO you're doing something wrong in your pom. First, you should use the Struts 2 Spring Plugin which handles integration for you. Second, you should use Maven to actually *handle* your transitive dependencies instead of just doing them manually anyway.

Comment: @DaveNewton: I want to use spring concept Ioc and DI in my struts2 web application. That's why need to integrate both in my app. Can u tell me the jar files which is needed/dependecies required for this integration in pom file?

Comment: You don't need spring 2 *and* spring 3 to use spring. Pick a version. You need the s2 spring plugin-that pulls in all the other dependencies. That's what maven is for: managing dependencies, so you don't have to. (usually)

Answer (score 0):

ContextLoaderPlugin is used with Struts 1. From the DOCTYPE in your struts.xml you're using Struts 2.

See here:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html#struts

For Struts 2 you should use the Struts2-Spring plugin.

Comment: I have used this plugin in my pom file. but still showing the same error when i deploy it on server. please help to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you remove the plugin declaration in struts config? Make sure you don't have any reference to org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn in your project.

Comment: I tried the application with removal of that struts2-spring-plugin in pom.xml but it showing the same error message. Could not initialize class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader. So can u please provide your help.